# If we restart Spring Boot application, what happened to the running user thread?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a question:
We are to restart/redeploy/republish a Spring Boot application.
If at the same time, there is a thread executing some business code(e.g. saving data to database), what will happen to the thread?
Is it possible that the database is in inconsistent state after the restart, and the requests we are processing all fail and we cannot remedy that?

Comment: IT depends on how the transaction is managed, if the transaction commits everything at the end of the business code, everything will just be discarded, if you are committing every single bit of data in the database, then you could have a situation like you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you restart the app all the thread will be lost and with this also the data the user entered.

If you have a relational database like Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL etc. then the connection will be lost and the transaction will rollback. Because of the ACID rule the data will not be in an inconsistent sate.